# C# Winforms ListBox items

Tags: c#, winforms, listboxitems

I have sevral text entries in a `listbox`, we'll call it `ListBox1`.

Ive been searching google, social.msdn.microsoft.com, and here. I cant figure out how to have each text entry change something when selected.

i.e

string1 causes `((value1 + value2) / 2)`

string2 cuases `((value3 + value4) / 2)`

string3 causes `((value5 + value6) / 2)`

Im obviously new.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to handle the [`ListBox.SelectedValueChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.selectedvaluechanged) event.

In main, or by using the designer, register the event handler:

```
listBox1.SelectedValueChanged += listBox1_SelectedValueChanged;
```

Then, your event handler:

```
void listBox1_SelectedValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    string value = listBox1.SelectedValue as string;
    if (value == null) return;

    // What to do now?
    switch(value) {
        case "string1":
            // Do something...
            break;

        case "string2":
            // Do something...
            break;

        case "string3":
            // Do something...
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: its giving me an error  `The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties: 'Program.Form1.ListBox1_SelectedValueChanged(object, System.EventArgs)' and 'Program.Form1.ListBox1_SelectedValueChanged(object, System.EventArgs)'`

Comment: I need some context to that error. What call? Are you sure you didn't accidentally define the handler method twice?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the SelectedIndexChanged event to execute code when items are selected. You can either test SelectedIndex or SelectedItem to see which item has been selected.

```
    private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (listBox1.SelectedItems.Count == 0)
            return;

        int selectedItemIndex = listBox1.SelectedIndex;
        string selectedItemText = listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();

        // E.g.
        this.Text = selectedItemText;
    }
```